# How can I modify my code to give the input in dict datatype?

Tags: python

My aim:
There is a record of n students.Each record contains student's name and their percent in math,physics,chemistry.The marks can be floating values.You are required to save the record in a dictionary data type.Student's name is the key.Marks store in a list is the value.The user enters a student's name.Output the average percentage marks obtained by that student.
This is my code:

```
n = int(input("Enter total number of students:"))

student_marks = {}

for x in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
student_name = input("Enter name of the student whose average you want:")

print("{0:.2f}".format(round(sum(student_marks[student_name]) / len(student_marks[student_name]), 2)))
```

I am actually getting this output:

```
Enter total number of students:3
Krishna 67 68 69
Arjun 70 98 63
Malika 52 56 60
Enter name of the student whose average you want:Malika
56.00
```

But I want my sample input to be in dict form containing marks as list i.e.,

```
Sample input: {'Krishna':[67,68,69],
               'Arjun':[70,98,63],
               'Malika':[52,56,60]}
```

How can I modify my code to give the input like this? without using import asl?
Please do help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not get the purpose of this question! You might not have noticed, but you already store your inputs to a dictionary data type called `student_marks`.

Comment: Do you want to input multiline dict literals, or just single-line literals?

Comment: single-line literals @MisterMiyagi

Comment: @ShreyaReddy Can you please provide proper sample input, then? The current sample input is a multiline dict literal.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

You can import the module ast and eval your input like below

```
import ast
input_dictionary = ast.literal_eval( input() )
```

Comment: It worked when I checked.. any reason why it will fail? I will edit if that's the case

Comment: The sample input is a multi-line string. ``input`` reads only a single line. It will fail with ``SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`` at the end of the first line.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I actually checked just by copying the input that is given in the question. But yes, if after every element of the dictionary, if the user types "enter" it will throw the error as you said. For the given situation, it is working though.

Answer (score 2):

Hey is this what you are looking for ?

Don't quite understand the question, but I hope this helps ....

Probably not the best in terms of efficiency, but it gets the job done, won't work if there's a student without grades, but you can probably fix it with extra logic

```
student_marks = {}

test = {'Krishna':[67,68,69],
               'Arjun':[70,98,63],
               'Malika':[52,56,60]}

    
_avg_scores = [sum(test[x])/(len((test[x]))) for x in test.keys()]


average_scores ={ list(test.keys())[i] : avg_scores[i] for i in range(len(_avg_scores)) }

student_name = input("Enter name of the student whose average you want:")


print(average_scores[student_name])
```

Comment: I was looking to pursue this question without using import ast. Thank  you.

Comment: I did not import anything :-)

Comment: yep.That's what I was looking for too.Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to have dict as input, so all you have to do is to convert  a str representation of a dict into a dict, for this you can use the built-in [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```py
import ast

n = input("Input as dict")
catalog = ast.literal_eval(n) # catalog object of <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Can this be done in any other way? Without import ast? @dejdej